# Declaring and using a variable within a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a Stored Procedure that calculates the number of days between two dates and also gets the double of the number. Currently my code looks like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn) As 'TotalDays',
DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn)*2 As '2TimesDays',
FROM tablename
```

I was wondering if there was another way of writing this, maybe there is a way of storing the `DATEDIFF(day...` inside a variable and simply writing `SELECT @Days As 'TotalDays', @Days*2 As '2TimesDays' From tablename`

> I tried to use this method:
> `Set @Days = (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn) FROM tablename)`,
>  but due to having multiple instances inside the table and wanting to print the total and double for all instances this did not work

My table looks somthing like this

```
+-------------------------+
| DateIn     | DateOut    |
+-------------------------+ 
| 10/11/2018 | 11/12/2018 |
| 11/13/2018 | 11/14/2018 |
| 12/01/2018 | 12/16/2018 |
| 12/30/2018 | 12/30/2018 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    t.TotalDays,
    t.TotalDays*2 AS [2TimesDays] FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn) As 'TotalDays'
        FROM tablename
    ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case, you can use `OUTER APPLY` as below

```
SELECT dateDif.days As 'TotalDays',
dateDif.days*2 As '2TimesDays',
FROM tablename
OUTER APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn) days 
             FROM tablename 
             WHERE <conditions>) dateDif
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the use of lateral joins -- `apply` -- for this purpose:

```
SELECT v.TotalDays, 2 * v.TotalDay as TotalDays_2
FROM tablename t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(day, DateOut, DateIn)) v(TotalDays);
```

Some advice.  Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  This will likely cause you problems in the future.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Give your columns (and tables and so on) names that do not need to be escaped -- that means, not starting with a number and not including spaces.  This makes queries easier to write and to read.